# Dailymotion addEventListener to play continuous video

Tags: javascript, dom-events, dailymotion-api

What I am trying to do is have a second video play right after the first finishes. I am aware that I need to trigger it with player.addEventListener but none of the methods seem to be working.

I copied and pasted the example code for a makeshift "playlist" but figured that the "ended" method had been deprecated and "video_end" should be used instead. But that doesn't work either. (example code: https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools/sdks#sdk-javascript-player-api)

Here is the basic html file. It plays the first video successfully but doesn't autostart the next:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id='player'></div>
<script src='https://api.dmcdn.net/all.js'></script>
<script>

var player = DM.player(document.getElementById('player'), {
video: 'xukthm',
params: {
    autoplay: true,
    mute: true
}
});

player.addEventListener('video_end', function (e)
{
e.target.load('xuktar');
});

</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue within a jsbin and everything seems to work as expected (See [jsbin sample](http://jsbin.com/tagozavuvo/edit?html,js,console). Make sure to open the [output panel](http://jsbin.com/tagozavuvo) as a standalone browser window/tab so the Flash player won't be blocked by JSBin). 

Are you sure there isn't something else in your way? Do you see a specific error in the browser console?

Comment: @dhar I did not know there was js browser console...Apparently the js script wasn't running because "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null')." I think it will work if I setup a legitimate server. Thanks so much for your help!